# Deleted question

Tags: support

There was an active question on how to put your opponents on cards.  It was a silly question that I VTC.

It is gone.  I (should) have privilege to see deleted questions.

I am OK that it is deleted deleted but what is going on?

Answer (score -1):

in my experience with the questions come up inline as deleted and it is just a placeholder showing where the deleted post is, none of the post is there. If there is a way to read what was deleted I don't know what it is.